# Replacing values of one dictionary with values from another dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to replace values in dictionary 1 with corresponding values from dictionary 2

I know that dictionary and list comprehensions will be useful here but am unsure as to how to apply them in this situation. What makes this especially confusing is that some of the values are in a list format but treated as strings.

```
# Matches proteins to corresponding drug ids #
dict1 = {'Protein 1' : '001, 002, 003', 'Protein 2' : '003, 004', 'Protein 3' : '002'}

# Matches drug ids with drug names #
dict2 = {'001' : 'Drug1', '002' : 'Drug2', '003' : 'Drug3', '004' : 'Drug4'}
```

I'd like to match corresponding drug names from dict2 to replace drug ids in dict 1 so that the output looks like this:

```
output_dict = {'Protein 1' : ['Drug1', 'Drug2', 'Drug3'], 'Protein 2' : ['Drug3', 'Drug4'], 'Protein 3' : ['Drug2']}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The input dictionary should be corrected beforehand (or by the program that produces it upstream), giving more sense to this answer. A simple dict comprehension with `split` will do:

```
dict1 = {'Protein 1' : '001, 002, 003', 'Protein 2' : '003, 004', 'Protein 3' : '002'}

dict1 = {k : v.split(", ") for k,v in dict1.items()}
```

now we have a list of strings as values, which makes more sense.

```
>>> dict1
{'Protein 1': ['001', '002', '003'],
 'Protein 2': ['003', '004'],
 'Protein 3': ['002']}
```

With that out of the way, just rebuild your dictionary using the translation dictionary with default value to original value to avoid key errors:

```
# Matches proteins to corresponding drug ids #
dict1 = {'Protein 1' : ['001', '002', '003'], 'Protein 2' : ['003', '004'], 'Protein 3' : ['002']}

# Matches drug ids with drug names #
dict2 = {'001' : 'Drug1', '002' : 'Drug2', '003' : 'Drug3', '004' : 'Drug4'}

dict3 = {k : [dict2.get(x,x) for x in v] for k,v in dict1.items()}
```

result:

```
>>> dict3
{'Protein 1': ['Drug1', 'Drug2', 'Drug3'],
 'Protein 2': ['Drug3', 'Drug4'],
 'Protein 3': ['Drug2']}
```

Answer (score 2):

A one-liner:

```
>>> dict1 = {'Protein 1' : '001, 002, 003', 'Protein 2' : '003, 004', 'Protein 3' : '002'}
>>> dict2 = {'001' : 'Drug1', '002' : 'Drug2', '003' : 'Drug3', '004' : 'Drug4'}
>>> {k: map(dict2.get, v.split(", ")) for k, v in dict1.items()}
{'Protein 1': ['Drug1', 'Drug2', 'Drug3'], 'Protein 2': ['Drug3', 'Drug4'], 'Protein 3': ['Drug2']}
```

For every list of codes `"001, ..."` in `dict1`, split the string and map the codes to the values in `dict2`

Answer (score 1):

This code will return output you asked for:

```
# Matches proteins to corresponding drug ids #
dict1 = {'Protein 1': ['001, 002, 003'], 'Protein 2': ['003, 004'], 'Protein 3': ['002']}

# Matches drug ids with drug names #
dict2 = {'001': 'Drug1', '002': 'Drug2', '003': 'Drug3', '004': 'Drug4'}


def string_replace_bulk(string, rules):
    result = string

    for old, new in rules.items():
        result = result.replace(old, new)

    return result


def weird_string_replace(src, rules):
    return [string_replace_bulk(s.strip(), rules) for s in src.split(',')]


def weird_list_replace(src, rules):
    result = {}
    for key, value in src.items():
        result[key] = []
        for item in value:
            result[key].extend(weird_string_replace(item, rules))

    return result


output_dict = weird_list_replace(dict1, dict2)

print(output_dict)
```

Result:

```
{'Protein 1': ['Drug1', 'Drug2', 'Drug3'], 'Protein 2': ['Drug3', 'Drug4'], 'Protein 3': ['Drug2']}
```

P.S. It's really weird input format, better to do something with it.